# Read out Facebook-Response single Value

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel

Im trying to login via Facebook from Angular. My Backend is Laravel.

I managed to get a Facebook-Code and exchange it to an access-token.

What i get in response right now looks like this in my console:

```
   {"access_token":"XXXXXXX","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5182122}
```

So im trying to get only the access-token in my php backend. How can i do this?

I tried several methods but non have worked so far. 
When trying to read it out i get a

> Cannot use object of type GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response as array

Error from Laravel.

Also i tried to read it out via foreach

```
 $responseArray = array();

       foreach ($token as $key => $value){
           $responseArray[] = $value;
       }

return($responseArray);
```

But the $responseArray is empty when returned to the Frontend.

Can anybody give me a hint?

EDIT:
Additional Information:

A.) How I get the code:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

       $token = $client->get($accessTokenUrl, ['query' => $params]);
return ($token);
```

B.) The JSON-String seems to be an Object. Here is what i get with a PostMan-Request.

Header:

```
content-length → 281
content-type → application/json; charset=UTF-8
date → Thu, 06 Aug 2015 19:15:24 GMT
expires → Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
facebook-api-version → v2.3
```

Body

```
{
  "access_token": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 5154312
}
```

var dump

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)#169 (6) {
  ["reasonPhrase":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["statusCode":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  int(200)
  ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  array(12) {
    ["access-control-allow-origin"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "*"
    }
    ["content-type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(31) "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
    ["x-fb-trace-id"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) "XXXXXXX"
    }
    ["x-fb-rev"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "XXXXXXX"
    }
    ["pragma"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "no-cache"
    }
    ["cache-control"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(44) "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    }
    ["facebook-api-version"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "v2.3"
    }
    ["expires"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    }
    ["x-fb-debug"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(88) "XXXXXXXXX=="
    }
    ["date"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Fri, 07 Aug 2015 11:32:55 GMT"
    }
    ["connection"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "keep-alive"
    }
    ["content-length"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "279"
    }
  }
  ["headerLines":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  array(12) {
    ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "*"
    }
    ["Content-Type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(31) "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
    ["X-FB-Trace-ID"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) "HkN84RYQnOf"
    }
    ["X-FB-Rev"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "1871945"
    }
    ["Pragma"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "no-cache"
    }
    ["Cache-Control"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(44) "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    }
    ["Facebook-API-Version"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "v2.3"
    }
    ["Expires"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    }
    ["X-FB-Debug"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(88) "XXXXXXXXXX=="
    }
    ["Date"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Fri, 07 Aug 2015 11:32:55 GMT"
    }
    ["Connection"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "keep-alive"
    }
    ["Content-Length"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "279"
    }
  }
  ["protocol":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  string(3) "1.1"
  ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#161 (7) {
    ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    resource(224) of type (stream)
    ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    NULL
    ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    string(10) "php://temp"
    ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That’s JSON data, so all you need to do is decode it …

Comment: using json_decode return following error: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: You don’t have an actual string value yet, so get the string value from whatever object you actually have here first.

Comment: Sorry but could you explain what you mean by getting the "string value from whatever object"? I dont really get it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I don’t know what type of object your `$token` is, because you have not shown any code about how you get that value. (If you’re unsure yourself, make a debug output using `var_dump`.)

Comment: Thank you CBroe, i added the Information. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the `var_dump` output?

Comment: I added the var_dump, just XXX'ed some values for security reasons.

Comment: Hey CBroe, i was able to fix it today. But stil, thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i managed to fix it. I'll post the answer just in Case anybody else comes across the same problem when trying to retrieve FacebookData via Guzzlehttp.

GuzzleHttpRequest:
**First we get the data and transform it to an string:**

```
 $request = $client->get($graphApiUrl, ['query' => $params]);
 $data = $request->getBody()->getContents();
```

**After that i used an foreachloop to read out the string and transform it to an array.**

```
 $dataArray = array();
            foreach (explode(",", $data) as $singleData) {
                list ($cKey, $cValue) = explode(':', $inf, 2);
                $dataArray[$cKey] = $cValue;
            }
```

**Afterwards simply read it out like this for example:**

```
return($dataArray['name']);
```